# Deploying Google Apps Scripts on different websites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a single Google Script that I have developed, yet it is a single script that should be placed on several  Google Sites pages, I would like to be able to know using the script which website has loaded my script.

How can the script identify which page has loaded it?

Comment: Is your script a Web App? Are the websites Google Sites? Will you be the one who adds the script to websites or how others will add the script?

Comment: You say that your "script should be placed on several pages".  Can you elaborate.  What kind of pages?

Comment: @Rubén My Script is a Google Script using HTML+JavaScript to work with Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: The Pages are webpages of Google Sites.

Comment: How do you will add the script to the websites?

Comment: Are you  using the new Google Sites or the classic Google Sites?

Comment: using the Apps Scripts Gadget Properties in a Google Sites Page

Comment: @Rubén, I think it is the classic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a web app inserted as gadget on Google Sites, to get the name of the site we could use [getActiveSite()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app#getactivesite) to get the Site object representing the active site and then [getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/site#getname), something like the following:

```
var mySite = SiteApp.getActiveSite();
var mySiteName = mySite.getName();
```

Comment: Done, @Ruben If I have a further question to ask you How Can I do this ?

Comment: @AYZAB : Please post a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334126/use-google-scripts-to-compare-google-site-vs-hyperlinks-in-spreadsheet